# How to validate choices fetched from database and then translated in symfony2? 

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

** update **

I've somehow found a way to set the callback option of the choice validator:

Part of my FormType.php:

```
\\ ABCFormType.php
$builder
    ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'ABCCommonBundle:Category',
        'query_builder' => function(\path\to\my\custom\repository\CategoryRepository $repo) {
            return $repo->findBaseLevel();
        },
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true, ));
```

Part of my custom repository:

```
\\ CategoryRepository.php
class CategoryRepository extends NestedTreeRepository
{
    private static $baseLevel = null;

    public function findCategoriesOfLevel($level = 0)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->where('p.lvl = :level')
                    ->setParameter('level', $level)
                    ->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC');

    }

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, ClassMetadata $class)
    {
        parent::__construct($em, $class);
        if (null == self::$baseLevel) {
            self::$baseLevel = $this->findBaseLevel()->getQuery()->getResult();
        }
    }

    public function findBaseLevel()
    {
        return $this->findCategoriesOfLevel(0);
    }

    public static function getBaseLevel()
    {
        return self::$baseLevel;
    }
```

Now I have a static method, so I set it up in the callback option of the choice validator:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="path\to\Entity\Category")
 * @Assert\Choice(callback="\path\to\CategoryRepository::getBaseLevel", min="1")
 * 
 * @var Category
 */
protected $categories;
```

Now it was confirmed that the correct "English" array had been fetched from the database, but since I translated the English category names into Chinese by symfony translation service, so although I did choose some choices but the validation was always fail!!!
Please help.

Comment: I think you can set `min` option. Or you can try to set NotBlank on $categories property on your entity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried those options you mentioned, but they failed. Actually, in choice constraint, either **choices** or **callback** option must be set.

Comment: Sorry for that. I was thinking that making it like a choice field (multiple = true and expanded = false) would be allow to use min: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is no need to add the Choice constraint to the property of your model. NotBlank constraint is enough to do the job. If you have a choice field type or any other that inherits from it (entity field type inherits from choice), then it will be automatically validated whether selected entity is in the given choices or not.

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="path\to\Entity\Category")
* @Assert\NotBlank()
* 
* @var Category
*/
protected $categories;
```

So your form could look like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('categories', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'ABCCommonBundle:Category',
        'query_builder' => function(\path\to\my\custom\repository\CategoryRepository $repo) {
            return $repo->findBaseLevel();
        },
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'property' => 'title',
    )
);
```

You can read more about *property* option here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

Now rendered checkboxes will look like this:

`<input type="checkbox" value="1" /> CategoryTitle`

Where value attribute will hold category primary key (it probably will be ID) and instead of CategoryTitle you'll see a **translated** Category::title value.